# VSCode unindents when typing closing parens

Tags: clojure, visual-studio-code

Using recent Visual Studio Code, if I have something like this:

```
(defn add [x y]
  (+ x y)
```

and then type a closing parens as the last character on the second line, the editor outdents the second line to the left margin. I mainly run into this sort of thing editing Clojure, but I tried the above in a Plain Text file to try to rule out extension problems, and I got the same outdenting behavior.

Does anyone know a setting I can change to disable this auto-outdenting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [`Parinfer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=narma.vscode-parinfer) for the following indentation behavior:

[image: The resulting behavior]

> `CTRL-p` (Linux and Windows) or `CMD-p` (macOS) for quick edit and `ext install vscode-parinfer`